# Markdown Syntax highlighting in Atom - bolding/italicizing partial words

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

In Atom editor, if I do this:

```
I only want to bold **t**he **f**irst **l**etter, 
or italicise in the m_iddl_e of a w_or_d
```

I can't. The bolding and italicizing don't start and stop in the right place.

(I don't know if this partial-word markup is part of the original MD spec. I use Pandoc for processing, and this produces the desired output --- but my source files become nearly unreadable in Atom.)

UPDATE:

The HTML output is fine. I am specifically trying to figure out how to fix **syntax highlighting in Atom**.

[image]

The asterisks in the middle of the word don't end the bolding by the syntax highlighter. That is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for. Are you talking about the output as shown with `markdown-preview` or the actual source in the editor view? The former works for me, except that I had to switch the underscores for single asterisks (bug?). Afaik, the latter case depends entirely on the theme you're using.

Comment: Could you post the HTML output you are getting as well as the HTML output you expected? And please only post the HTML (view source if you have to). A screenshot will not be helpful.

Comment: The HTML output is fine. 

I am only specifically talking about syntax highlighting when looking at the markdown source in the Atom editor.